# Ubuntu 18.04 install fails on new laptop "watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!"

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I just purchased an Acer Aspire A315-41-R3RF. It comes with a Ryzen 3 2200U processor. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04, which I just downloaded. I boot into the USB stick, choose the option to try Ubuntu, and I immediately get these errors:

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s!
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s!
```

They just loop perpetually. Windows 10 (which was preinstalled) runs fine. I disabled secure boot in the BIOS. Any ideas?

I should add that the USB stick is good -- it worked fine on another system.

Comment: Did you verify the checksums of the download? Possibly corrupt.

Comment: Yes, I did. Checksum was fine. The same stick installed fine on another laptop.

Comment: That's good, at least. There's a 4yo possibly-related post [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211) saying this may be a hardware issue, specifically power supply. If it's possible to change the CPU and/or GPU clock through the BIOS have you tried that at all? It can be dangerous of course, so proceed with caution. Beyond that you could try installing an older version of Ubuntu and upgrading after, or try [18.04.1 instead of just 04(http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) if that is actually the version you're using (even the site says 18.04 but points to 18.04.01).

Comment: The only way that I could get Linux installed was to install Debian Stretch, plug in an Ethernet cable and let it do updates during install. I tried 2 versions of Ubuntu and Arch. They all croaked.

Comment: That's interesting. Did you get any possibly-useful logs for them? IDK much, but one of the smarter users around here may understand what went wrong and/or why.

Comment: Arch and Ubuntu weren't usable enough to access logs. All I really had was pages of the error above. I think it has something to do with the Ryzen 3 processor not being properly supported by those versions, but I don't know for sure. It _should_ be supported, because Ryzen has been out for a while, but who knows. I also got "AHCI error"  fairly often.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I had replied earlier -- didn't actually have anything at that point though, but I thought of your problems with installing Ubuntu when I saw this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1074792/411468. May be worth a look, though obviously you've surpassed the need anyways.