# Ubuntu 18.04 Install Freezes the CPU

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, intel-cpu

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS9560 with an Intel Core i7-7700HQ and It was freezing up on the splash screen.  I started it again and disabled the splash screen in the GRUB command line and I saw it freeze with these repeated "soft lockups" on several different processes.  I'm pretty sure it's not a low-level hardware failure because I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Kubuntu 18.04 installed on two different partitions of this computer and both work fine.

[image]

Sorry for the low image quality.  It's a phone picture because a screenshot won't work.  Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can try, in order

1) Add `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"` to your kernel command line.

2) Add `clocksource=tsc` to your kernel command line.

3) Add `pci=nommconf` to your kernel command line.

I think the first one is the best bet.  I have an XPS and it cleared up some occasional (sometimes often) CPU lockups.  Something weird with the Dell bios or something, I am not really sure what it does.

[acpi_osi](https://askubuntu.com/a/50776/411468)

[tsc](https://superuser.com/a/393978/928285)

[pci=nommconf](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-9629/README/appendix-l.html) (Ctrl-F "nommconf"; there was no easy link).